# jquery centering span on image hover (because it is inline maybe?)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make fancy hover effect when contents is revealed when user hovers image. I want hover bubble to be centered and on the top of images.

Illustrated in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sandrodz/TnEMU/

It is especially bad in chrome, where span which is automatically turned to display:inline on hover behaves differently from firefox. Putting both as block elements helps but hidden element is pan and it automatically gets display:inline. Any thoughts on how to fix this problem and make hover appear directly on top of correct images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [There you go (with your code)](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/8NJvX/8/)

The `CSS` changes:

```
#features_icons li span {
    top:0; /* ///added to fix in chrome ///*/
    left:0;/* ///added to fix in chrome///*/
    white-space:nowrap;/* ///added this line/// */
}
#features_icons li {
    position:relative;  /* ///added this line/// */
}
```

And inside jquery I just added: `outerWidth(true)` to get the right dimensions:

```
spanW = ($(this).next("span").outerWidth(true) / 2) - ($(this).outerWidth(true) / 2);
```

---

You can also try: removing all of your `<SPAN>` elements
**a different approach:**

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/UK3NG/)*

In any case your icons need an alt attribute... so why not give the SPAN text to each image: (any CMS editor allows you to add *alt. description* text to images.)

```
<img alt="Air Conditioning" src="http:conditioning.png" />
```

So you can remove ALL your spans, append after the `<body>` tag this:

```
<div id="tooltip"></div>
```

and use my script:

```
$("ul#features_icons li img").hover(function() {
           var altText = $(this).attr('alt');
           var thisW2   = $(this).outerWidth(true) / 2;
           var thisPosL = $(this).offset().left + thisW2;
           var thisPosT = $(this).offset().top;
           
           $('#tooltip').text(altText);
           var toolW2 = $('#tooltip').outerWidth(true) / 2; // after it's filled with text
           $('#tooltip').stop(1).fadeTo(200,1).css({left: (thisPosL-toolW2) , top:thisPosT});
    }, function() {
        $('#tooltip').fadeTo(100,0,function(){
           $(this).hide();
        });
    });
```

- It will calculate the icon position
- grab the `alt` text
- fill `#tooltip` with thext
- Get the tooltip width
- position the `#tooltip`
- and show it!

P.S: I just renamed in your CSS: `#features_icons li span {` to `#tooltip{`

Comment: Wow, this is extensive. And I like your approach with ALT I wish I thought of that before. At this point I cannot change html anymore. But in first example (my version ur fix) look at "accessible for disabled" it is not quite centered.  Any ideas why?

Comment: @SandroDzneladze Thanks for your likes! :) Sure I know why: you have inline styles for your `span` element: `<span style="margin-left: -41.5px; display: none; ">Accessible for Disabled</span>` you see? :) just remove that styles! : http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/8NJvX/8/

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take http://jsfiddle.net/XrTZg/30/

I moved the spans before the img. I removed the unecessary margins (spans inline css + css file).

I made the span `display: absolute;`, i wanted it to be positioned relative to the parent element, so i set `#features_icons li` to be `display: relative;`.

I also fixed the top and left offset of the span, in JS.